# Как ужать код в 1 красивую строчку?

Tags: php

```
for ($i = 0; $i < mb_strlen($in); $i++) {
    if ($i > 350 && mb_substr($in, $i, 1) == '.') {
        $endstr = mb_substr($in, $i + 1);
        $endstr = preg_replace("/^\s*/u", '', $endstr);
        $in     = mb_substr($in, 0, $i) . ".\n" . $endstr;
        break;
    }
}
```

Кто меньше ? Суть сей процесса в том чтобы сделать перенос с тексте примерно после 350 знака, после первой точки.
Эта - Очень страшная конструкция.

Спасибо.

Comment: Блин, да !

 $in=preg_replace("/(.{150}[^\.]*\.)\s*/u","$1\n",$in);

Я долго не мог допереть до этой регулярки. Спасибо !!!!!

Comment: Видимо незнание возможностей глубокой оптимизации в интерпретаторе ПХП повергает меня в глубокое уныние при виде **if** проверяющего длину строки внутри **for** на каждом шаге которого вычисляется посредством вызова функции **эта длина**...

А может все проще ? Неужели производители железа приплачивают авторам подобного кода (или их учителям) ?

Кстати, использование preg_replace() для решения данной задачи тоже из этой же области.

Comment: @avp Хобби: конспирология?

Comment: Нет, просто неуклюжая попытка устыдить таких писателей.

Comment: Я люблю однострочные решения, даже если они непотимальны по скорости,  дак как же правильно тогда реализовать задачу по вашему ?
если не форами и не preg_replace, чем же ?

Comment: @avp Библиотека pcre сколько уже лет существует? Её вроде вылизывать стараются.

Comment: Я не сомневаюсь, что pcre хорошая библиотека. 

Просто это из пушки по воробьям. 

Надо найти точку после 350-го символа в строке и склеить результат из подстроки (от начала до точки (вкл. ее)), "\\n" и остатка строки (от точки до конца). 

Просто, понятно, эффективно и поэтому легко  модифицируемо при сопровождении.

Не поверю, что ПХП нет аналога strchr() из C. "Однострочность" достигается оформлением нескольких строк кода в собственную функцию.

Comment: Которую (собственную функцию) всё равно надо тащить на сервер. Здесь использование регекспов кажется вполне оправданным.

Comment: Неужели в ПХП нет статических (локальных для данного файла) функций ?

Не верю.

И поосторожнее с регекспами - богатая почва для трудноуловимых ошибок при изменении формата входных данных. К поиску точки данное замечание не относится.

Comment: Я пхп-то и не знаю. Просто я писал про то, что файл-то живёт на сервере.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/(.{200}[^.]*\.)\s*/u` поменять на `$1\n`